# Getting Error Connect to Oracle using Python On Mac - Cannot locate Oracle Client library

Tags: python, oracle, macos

I'm trying to connect to Oracle database in Python on Mac but getting the following error:

**cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See
https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help**

The code causing the error is
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host='', port='', service_name='')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='', password='', dsn=dsn_tns)

Using the cx_Oracle Library

This is my lib folder

$ ls -la ~/lib

total 274272

drwxr-xr-x    7   staff        224 Jun 25 13:31 .

drwxr-xr-x+ 113   staff       3616 Jun 25 14:20 ..

lrwxr-xr-x    1   staff         61 Jun 24 18:03 libclntsh.dylib -> /Users/username/oracle/instantclient_19_3/libclntsh.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x    1   staff         51 Jun 25 13:31 libclntsh.dylib.19.1 -> /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_1/libclntsh.dylib.19.1

-rwxr-xr-x@   1   staff    4803832 Jun 24 18:31 libclntshcore.dylib.19.1

-rwxr-xr-x@   1   staff    8349944 Jun 24 18:30 libnnz19.dylib

-rwxr-xr-x@   1   staff  125518764 Jun 24 18:31 libociei.dylib

MacOS: Catalina Version 10.15.5
Python 3.7.7
Oracle client

Answer (score 0):

In cx_Oracle 8 there is a new initialization method that you can call in your scripts to specify the Instant Client directory:

```
import platform

if platform.platform()[:6] == 'Darwin':
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="/Users/cjones/instantclient_19_3")
```

You can also add a symlink in the appropriate site-packages directory, but I think `init_oracle_client()` is easier.

Check the updated [installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-macos) and the new [initialization documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html).

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply Christopher but apparently setting DYLD_LIBRAY_PATH in MacOS Catalina Version 10.15 does not help.

Comment: cx_Oracle 8 was released today. I've updated my answer with details,

Comment: BTW, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH worked on Catalina when I [tested it](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/341#issuecomment-643931772).

Comment: Your if statement should be platform.system() to check whether it is indeed Darwin or not,

Comment: Yes. All my recent examples use something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more detailed step by step instruction:

1. Download Basic Package (ZIP) from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html. Unzip file and keep the folder instantclient_19_8 (or whatever the most recent version is called) in your Downloads folder.
2. Assuming you already have cx_Oracle, sys, and os packages installed in your python, run below in python:

   ```
    import cx_Oracle
    import sys
    import os

    lib_dir = os.path.join(os.environ.get("HOME"), "Downloads", "instantclient_19_8")
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=lib_dir)
   ```

Comment: This is also discussed in the cx_Oracle installation instructions: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-macos-intel-x86